# Cannot delete attribute file in mac os X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, filesystems, file-attributes

Suddenly some *attributes files started to appeared in the `trash folder` of my mac os x (snow leopard).

The problem is I can't delete them.

```
// 1. See there is a file with an invalid name 
MAC:libs cran$ ls
commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes

// 2. That I can't delete  
MAC:libs cran$ rm commons-io-2.0.1.jar\:com.dropbox.attributes 
rm: commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes: No such file or directory

// 3. The only file here
MAC:libs cran$ ls -a
.
..
commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes

// 4. But I can't do anything with it
MAC:libs cran$ ls -l
ls: commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes: No such file or directory

// 5. Trying to delete parent folder
MAC:iome.desktop cran$ rm -rf libs
rm: libs: Directory not empty

// 6. Trying to use wildcards 
MAC:libs cran$ rm commons-*
rm: commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes: No such file or directory

// 7. Trying to delete parent folder
MAC:iome.desktop cran$ rmdir libs
rm: libs: Directory not empty

// 8. Retrieving the inode
MAC:libs cran$ ls -i
ls: commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes: No such file or directory
3408401 commons-io-2.0.1.jar

// 8. Remove the file by inode
MAC:libs cran$ find . -inum 3408401 -exec rm -i {} \;
remove ./commons-io-2.0.1.jar? y
find: ./commons-io-2.0.1.jar:com.dropbox.attributes: No such file or directory

// 9. Repair the disk permission 

// 10. Fix the ACL (while booting from an external drive)
```

I ran a `fsck -fy` hoping that it would clean them, but to no avail.
I want to install bootcamp on my computer. But now that I feel that the filesystem is messed, I'm a bit afraid about creating new partitions and whatnot.

I tried to use `xattr` to remove the file, but once again, to no avail :

```
MAC:libs cran$ touch commons-io-2.0.1.jar

// a. Trying to remove attr 
MAC:libs cran$ xattr -d com.dropbox.attributes commons-io-2.0.1.jar 
xattr: commons-io-2.0.1.jar: No such xattr: com.dropbox.attributes

// b. Trying to remove attr 
MAC:libs cran$ xattr -d com.dropbox commons-io-2.0.1.jar 
xattr: commons-io-2.0.1.jar: No such xattr: com.dropbox
```

I ran all those tests in normal mode and single user mode.
Do you know how I can get rid of those files ?

Comment: `find -delete` didn't work either?

Comment: I haven't tested it. But `find ... rm` didn't. Fortunately, I don't have the files anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hat off to the **genuises of the Apple Store of Lyon Part Dieu, France**.

The rationale behind the solution is : if you can't delete something, try to move it some other place.

What **Adrien and Vincent** did :

- rename `.trash` to `badtrash`
- create another `.trash` folder. Now my trash is working as expected but the undeletable files are still on my computer. But wait, there is more :)
- boot the mac from another system located on an `external harddrive`
- change the permission of `badtrash` so it can be deleted
- delete `badtrash`
- empty the trash

Tadah !

Now my undeletable files are now on the external drive.
Which is not a problem : neither for me, neither for Adrien and Vincent as the external drive will be reformatted soon.

Classy solution, eh ?

Thanks to the great Apple store team at Lyon Part Dieu.

Answer (score 0):

While in that directory, try:

`rm commons`

and then press the `Tab` key (this should autocomplete the file name) and after that `Enter`.

Disclaimer: I am not sure if deleting such files could cause any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that (see 2.) but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't realize that it came from autocomplete. What if you try `rm commons*`? or if you delete the whole directory from one level up?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work either (I updated the question with 5, 6 and 7). But nice ideas, by the way.

Comment: Also, what xattr option did you try? One thing that I am not sure is what happens with the extended attributes when the original file is missing, this may have something to do with the problem and you may need to create a fake original file to delete the atributes with xattr, say `touch commons-io-2.0.1.jar` and then `xattr -c commons-io-2.0.1.jar`

Comment: Already did that. But it failed too. Somehow I feel I have to use low level utils : directly manipulating `inodes` or something like that. Because the file is obviously invalid so I doubt that the file system could return a valid file descriptor for my attributes files...

Comment: Updated with results a. and b.